# Tracking in Boujou and exporting to Blender

Tags: .fbx

Tracking in Boujou and exporting to Blender. Hello! I started to learn about tracking in Blender. But I didn't get a good result. I have a rather complex scene in Blender with bone animation and several emitters with partials.  Unfortunately the task of work is very urgent and I turned to the program Boujou. I then definitely want to go back to Blender tracking, but now the question is about exporting to Blender from Boujou. I received from Boujou FBX, the tracking was fine. But Blender is not accepting correctly - there is a noticeable parallax between the 3d object and the frame sequences. I spent all day experimenting with scaling and other settings in Boujou, the results were consistently bad. Then I tried this FBX in Maya and made sure that the export is done perfectly and the error is in Blender. I have the latest version 2.93 downloaded 2-3 days ago. How do I properly import the camera from Boujou into Blender?

Comment: It would help if you gave a sample of the tracking data exported and your blender project. Your question currently doesn't tell us enough to know how to help

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking a question on this site. I have prepared a video showing the error. Blender, Maya, Boujou, FBX, Tracking at Boujou. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Hy47IEwye4

Comment: I'm afraid without the files themselves I can't help. Perhaps someone else knows this exact problem.

Comment: I was prompted for the answer below. And at the same time my friend on social media. The sensor fit should have been set to vertical in the camera settings. I have a vertical frame format. And the setting was automatic. Thanks, for the answer everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very specific scenario :O  I suspect maybe Blender does get the camera animation correctly, but not the camera & render settings themselves. So i'd suggest you to check the render resolution, aspect ratio, and the field of view of the camera.

Comment: L0Lock, thank you very much for your reply. You and my friend were both right at the same time.The Sensor fit should have been set to vertical in the camera settings. You made my day, I will sleep like a baby tonight. I spent 3 days tracking and half of it exporting to Blender from Boujou.

Comment: Also, thank you very much for the advice on how to use the forum! I'm sorry I didn't mark the answer right away. I ticked it off. 8))